# Setting up a for loop in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to create a batch file which scans a folder for files

```
for /R D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\ %%f in (*.xml) do(
    copy %%f "\\destination"
    if errorlevel 0 move %%f "D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\archive\"
)
```

**FIXED** - *But it won't work. If I execute it, it only prints the first line of code*. **It works now. I added a space after the "do (" and now it executes.**

1) is my second command ok? I want to move the copied file in an archive if everything went well with the first command.

2) how should i change the loop to work only on the files in the given directory and not the subdirectories in it?

Comment: `if !errorlevel! equ 0 move...`

Comment: so you want copy without overwriting?

Comment: try with `copy /y copy "%%~ff" "\\destination"`

Comment: @npocmaka it should skip the copy if the file is already there.

Comment: @darkfang what's the difference with my code? Sorry but I've never used batch files for more advanced things.

Comment: you should have space after `do`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You are missing a space between the `do` and the parenthesis
- The construct `if errorlevel n` is evaluated to true for any errorlevel value equal or greater to n, so `if errorlevel 0` will be true for any non negative errorlevel value. You should use `if not errorlevel 1`
- It is a good habit to quote all paths just in case something could include a space or a special character

```dos
for /R "D:\path\import_orders\xml_files" %%f in (*.xml) do (
    copy "%%~ff" "\\destination"
    if not errorlevel 1 move "%%~ff" "D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\archive\"
)
```

To avoid the directory recursion, just change the `for` loop, removing the `/R` (that asks for recursion) moving the start folder tip to the file selection pattern.

```dos
for %%f in ("D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\*.xml") do (
    copy "%%~ff" "\\destination"
    if not errorlevel 1 move "%%~ff" "D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\archive\"
)
```

But in any case `copy` command does not ask for confirmation if target file exists. If you don't want to overwrite the existing file you have some options

**Use the switches of the `copy` command**

You can use `/-y` so `copy` command will ask for confirmation before overwritting the file, and to automate the process you can pipe the answer to the question

```
echo n|copy /-y "source" "target"
```

This is the approach in the [npocmaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32903711/2861476). This approach should work without problems but

- It is necessary two create two `cmd` instances to handle each of the sides of the pipe, and to do it for each of the source files, so it will slow the process
- It could fail if the code is executed on a locale where the overwrite question is not waiting a `N` character as a negative answer.

**First check for file presence**

You can use the builtin `if exist` construct to first check if the target file is present

```
if not exist "\\destination\%%~nxf" copy "%%~ff" "\\destination"
```

where `%%~nxf` if the name and extension of the file being processed

So, the final code could be

```dos
for %%f in ("D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\*.xml") do (
    if not exist "\\destination\%%~nxf" copy "%%~ff" "\\destination"
    if not errorlevel 1 move "%%~ff" "D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\archive\"
)
```

Comment: in the comments it's mentioned that the copy should be without overwriting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem is that as you can see from the second command the folder \archive is a subfolder of xml_files. I've tried your example and the for is looping also through the archived fiels. Any way to avoid it from recursively search for files in subfolders?

Comment: @nowhere, I think I modified the answer while you were reading. It is included at the end.

Comment: @MCND Great answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @nowhere, I were re-reading the answer and I realized there is two non defined points. If a file is present in target and it is skipped, is this an error and the `move` should also be skipped? What to do if the source file is also present in archive?

Comment: @MCND I was actually thinking about it... can the move be skipped if the file is already there? Oh i see now your edit.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for /R "D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\" %%f in (*.xml) do (
    (echo n|copy /-y "%%~ff" "\\destination"|find /i "0 file(s) copied." >nul 2>&1)||(
       move "%%~ff" "D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\archive\"
    )
)
```

edit without searching subdirectories:

```
for %%f in ("D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\*.xml") do (
    (echo n|copy /-y "%%~ff" "\\destination"|find /i "0 file(s) copied." >nul 2>&1)||(
       move "%%~ff" "D:\path\import_orders\xml_files\archive\"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this also check the subfolders recursively? Cause I'm looking only for the files in the given dir "\xml_files\".

Comment: @nowhere  - yes. It will copy without overwrite and if the copy is sucessfull it move the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i selected MC's answer just cause it's better explained. voted up anyway.